# How to apply the same font size to multiple Texts within an HStack and size the HStack to fit its parent?

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack, dynamic-resizing, swiftui-text

I have an `HStack` with three `Texts`:

```
HStack {
    Text("Hey")
    Text(".")
    Text("What's up?")
}
```

All I want is the `HStack` to fill the available space of its parent container under the constraint that all three `Texts` have the same font size in the end.

The following naive approach obviously doesn't work:

```
struct ThreeTextsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hey")
            Text(".")
            Text("What's up?")
        }
        .font(.system(size: 500)) // set a crazy-height font-size
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01) // so it can be scaled down
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200) // ← this only simulates the size of the container
    }
}
```

This is the output:

[image: Rendered view]

Each `Text` view is scaled individually according to the preferences applied to the whole `HStack`, so we end up with three different font sizes in the same `HStack`. Of course, I could use a fixed font size instead, but then the compound of the three texts would not dynamically fill its container when the container is resized.

#### How can I solve this (without magic numbers and additional assumptions)?

The three `Texts` must be baseline-aligned in the end. (That's clearly not the case in the example above.)

*Note:* John Sundell has written [a great article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/questions/syncing-the-width-or-height-of-two-swiftui-views/) on how to give views an equal width or height based on their intrinsic (ideal) sizes. However, my problem is a little different as it also requires knowledge of the outside world (the container's size), so it has one additional constraint.

Comment: have you tried custom layouts via the Layout protocol?

Comment: No. Didn't know about those until a minute ago... would that be a good tool for the job? Will look into them.

Comment: If you were to set a ```lineLimit``` of 1 then it could be achieved quite easily using ```Text``` concatenation. But if the three text blocks can wrap independently then it's more complicated...

Comment: In my specific use case, I actually want one-liners. However, I need to use an `HStack` because I want to align the entire thing with respect to the dot (second `Text`)  in the end. I guess it's hard to base a layout guide on a character position in a concatenated string... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there is an easy solution. You just need to add `.scaledToFit`... but it must come before the frame! The modifier `minimumScaleFactor` is still needed too:

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Hey")
        Text(".")
        Text("What's up?")
    }
    .font(.system(size: 500)) // set a crazy-height font-size
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.01) // so it can be scaled down
    .scaledToFit() // MUST BE BEFORE FRAME!
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200) // ← this only simulates the size of the container
}
```

[image: ScaledToFit]

---

*EDIT*

Actually, if you look closely you will notice that the height of the third block is slightly less than the first block - they are not perfectly aligned.

It works better if you use zero spacing on the `HSTack` and then include `Text` spacers between the blocks (if you need spacing at all):

```swift
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 0) {
    Text("Hey")
    Text("  ")
    Text(".")
    Text("  ")
    Text("What's up?")
}
.font(.system(size: 50)) // set a crazy-height font-size
.minimumScaleFactor(0.01) // so it can be scaled down
.scaledToFit() // MUST BE BEFORE FRAME!
.frame(width: 200, height: 200) // ← this only simulates the size of the container
```

[image: ZeroSpacing]

Answer (score 0):

I see many ways to solve this, but concentrating on requirement to have the same font size for all text entities, the simplest is to use `Text(_:format:)` like this:

```
struct ThreeTextsView: View {
    var values = [ // <-- all the text parts are just strings
        "Hey",
        ".",
        "What's up?"
    ]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(values, format: SimpleJoin()) // <-- we display them in one Text element, 
                                               // so their style is consistent 
        }
        .font(.system(size: 500)) 
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01) 
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

and the SimpleJoin is just

```
struct SimpleJoin: FormatStyle {
    func format(_ value: [String]) -> String {
        value.joined()
    }
}
```

this solution also supports setting a line limit to 1 for the entire text (which will reduce the font):

```
Text(values, format: SimpleJoin())
    .lineLimit(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this nice idea! Unfortunately, it does not answer the question as the base assumption is that I have three `Texts` in an `HStack`. (I need separate `Texts` for alignment reasons as explained in more detail in a comment on the question above.)